# Changing the object a pointer points to in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm creating a game, and I have a array of pointers to hero objects. Only one hero should be active at a time, so I have a separate pointer to the active hero. 
If it matters, I'm using Qt, and the Hero class inherits from QgraphicsItem.

it is important that I am able to switch between Hero's, so I've written the following piece of code:

```
void Game::toggleHero()
{

    if(activeHero==hero[0])
    {
        activeHero  =hero[1];
        hero[1]->setFocus();
    }
    else if(activeHero == hero[1])
    {
        activeHero = hero[0];
        hero[0]->setFocus();
    }
}
```

The problem is, that that method does what I expect it to do, but only the first time it is called. The activeHero newer changes back to the original object.

The array of Hero objects are members of a game class, and are initialized in the game object's constructor. The only time activeHero is ever referenced is when a hook item is added, or when the setView() method is called.

```
class Game : public QGraphicsView
{
public:
Game();
Terrain *ground[63];
Wall *wall[63];
Ladder *ladder[63];
Bushes * bush;
QGraphicsScene * scene;
Hero *hero[1];
Hero *activeHero;
void buildLevel(int level);
void setView();
void toggleHero();

};
```

From the game object's constructor:
    //add hero
    hero[0] = new Hero();
    hero[0]->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusable);
    hero[0]->setFocus();
    scene->addItem(hero[0]);
    hero[0]->setPos(5,1200);
    // activeHero = hero[0];
    hero[1] = new Hero();
    hero[1]->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusable);
    hero[1]->setFocus();
    scene->addItem(hero[1]);
    hero[1]->setPos(10,1300);
    activeHero = hero[0];

The setView() method checks if the active hero is in view, and if it isn't it moves the view so that the activeHero is at the correct spot relative to the view.

```
void Game::setView()
{

if((!(activeHero->pos().y()+activeHero-           >rect().height()/2==sceneRect().y()+sceneRect().height()/2-400)&&((activeHero-        >y()+activeHero->rect().height()/2-400>0))&&(activeHero->y()+activeHero->rect().height()-400<1600))){

    setSceneRect(sceneRect().x(),activeHero->pos().y()+activeHero->rect().height()/2-400,800,600);

}
if((!(activeHero->pos().x()+activeHero->rect().width()/2==sceneRect().x()+sceneRect().width()/2))&&((activeHero->x()+activeHero->rect().width()-450>0)&&(activeHero->x()+activeHero->rect().width()+350<3200))){
    setSceneRect(activeHero->pos().x()+activeHero->rect().width()/2-400,sceneRect().y(),800,600);
}
```

And finally, a Hook object uses the activeHero to position itself in the scene.

```
Hook::Hook(int direction)
{
hookdirection = direction;
switch(hookdirection)
{
case -1:
{
setRect(0,0,16,16);
setPos(game->activeHero->pos());
break;
}
case 1:
{
    setRect(0,0,16,16);
    setPos(game->activeHero->pos().x()+game->activeHero->rect().width()-    rect().width(),game->activeHero->pos().y());
    break;
}
default:
{
    setRect(0,0,16,16);
    break;
}

}
timer = new QTimer;
connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(move()));
timer->start(10);

lineItem = new QGraphicsLineItem();
lineItem->setParentItem(this);
game->activeHero->scene()->addItem(lineItem);

}
```

The objective of the toggleHero method is to switch between hero[0], and hero[1] so that each of them is the activeHero in the methods above.

Comment: There's not nearly enough information to solve the problem here. Please show us where `activeHero` and the `hero` array are declared (and initialized) and make a note of any other major changes that may occur to these variables.

Answer (score -1):

If hero is a pointer you need decide whether to compare the heroes (eg. by name with overloaded operators) or the adresses. So it should be:

```
if(*activeHero==hero[0])
    {
        *activeHero  =hero[1];
        hero[1]->setFocus();
    }
    else if(*activeHero == hero[1])
    {
        *activeHero = hero[0];
        hero[0]->setFocus();
    }
```

or it should be

```
if(activeHero==&hero[0])//address of hero[0]
{
    activeHero  =&hero[1];
    hero[1]->setFocus();
}
else if(activeHero == &hero[1])
{
    activeHero = &hero[0];
    hero[0]->setFocus();
}
```

Comment: Not necessarily.  From `hero[1]->setFocus()` it follows that `hero` is an array of pointers. And from `activeHero  =hero[1];` activeHero is a pointer.
With entity semantics, a hero is represented by a *unique* object, and can then be identified by its address. hero[0] is such an address.